# How to design my solution

Tags: c#, projects-and-solutions

I am writing a web application which will include several parts - interactive calendar, todo list, managing finances,...

How should I design my solution? I thought something like this: each part has 3 projects (main project, DAL, BLL). 
So in my case I would have 9 projects in my solution:

- List item
- Calendar
- CalendarDAL
- CalendarBLL
- Todo
- TodoDAL
- TodoBLL
- Money
- MoneyDAL
- MoneyBLL

Would this design be OK?

Also: where should web.config be? In it I have a connectionString which I would like to call from all DAL projects. Now I had web.config file in Calendar project and when I wanted to create dataAdapter in CalendarDAL with designer, I couldn't use existing connectionString from web.config.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, just to make sure you are developing using ASP.NET. And what does DAL and DLL stand for?

Comment: Dal is Data Access Layer. I think _simon_ probably meant BLL (Business Logic Layer) instead of DLL.

Comment: Sorry, I meant BLL (Business Logic Layer)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you need to be able to separate and use the logic of this code in multiple applications, there is really no need to separate it into that many projects. It adds complexity but doesn't really add value. I used to separate the general BL library from the DL library but realized I wasn't really getting anything out of it...and I was making some things more annoying in the process. **What is most important in separating code is the logical separation, not the physical separation into separate dlls**.

Also, instead of breaking this up into separate web apps, put them in one. It will be a lot easier to develop and deploy. This allows you to use one web.config. If they are separate websites then create different web projects. If they are not, then don't.

**[Edited]**
One thing I meant to add, which is important, is this: The question of how you should design this is actually too general to really come up with a real answer. Those thoughts are just my general thoughts on project organization, which is what the question really seemed to revolve around.

Comment: I guess you are right... first I thought it would be just one project and therefore I added new folder and then some subfolders... Now I have problems with namespaces, because they are somehow 'mixed' together. A friend of mine suggested, that I should design my solution this way (seperate projects for DAL, BLL) so I asked here. I will try to use common logic and design my solution easier way. Thanks

Comment: Separate projects prohibit circular references. This can be useful for enforcing a View-down, layered hierarchy which in turn aids code simplicity and clarity through design. It also stops junior X from butchering your pattern.

Answer (score 1):

read up on MVC or nTier programming.

three basic layers:

1. your view: the aspx web pages
2. a controller: allows the view to interact with the model (kinda like encapsulation) it's just one class that acts as a go between.
3. a model: in here is your database/xmldata and your functionality. this is where the magic happens.

work in increments. first make the most basic of websites. then add functionality (one new feature at a time) , test it then move on.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion a good, layered .Net application architecture should have the following projects (structure) in the solution:

- Presentation layer: Here's where the web.config resides, your ASPX pages and user controls (ascx)
- Interface layer for the business logic layer: A layer containing exclusively interfaces of your business logic layer
- The business logic layer classes: The classes implementing the interfaces of the interface layer (point above)
- Interface layer for the data access logic: Again, exclusively interfaces of your data access layer
- The data access layer classes: The same as for the business layer; the implementations of the interfaces of the layer before

This sounds quite complicated but represents a good separation of the logical layers. So for instance you could exchange your business logic layer or more probably (and realistically) your data access layer DLL without changing anything above since everything is separated by the according interface layers from each other.

To what regards the separation of the different projects you mentioned (i.e. Calendar, Todo, etc...) I'm not really sure. The question you have to pose is to whether these things are independent applications or whether they belong together. Modularization is important, but has to be thought of very well. What I for instance would separate is like when you have a project with different kind of UI's, one for the Administrator and one for the normal user. Here it could make sense to **just exchange the presentation layer**, the rest below could remain the same. So you could for instance put the admin presentation layer + the other logical layers below inside a solution and the user UI presentation layer + the (same) logical layers in another solution. This may make sense when different development teams are developing each of the solutions.

In your case it seems to me more of being a single project, so I would just group them internally in different user controls/namespaces, but not create a project (-> DLL) for each of them. This adds just complexity without any major advantage.

Comment: I wouldn't treat interfaces as separate layer. Interfaces represent layer itself. This means that if you have interface IDataProvider, then every data provider is IDataProvider.  Other layers shouldn't know that we have MySqlDataProvider or others. They just take IDataProvider and use it. Concrete clases belong to the same level. Moreover, I think that good idea is to hide (as internal) concrete classes in the assembly where their interface defined. This is not suitable in some cases, but you should try :) It will make architecture more foolproof.

Comment: I fully agree. I don't abstract things in the interface layers such as provider interfaces since these are just used internally in the DAO layer. In the interface layers I just expose interfaces that should be exposed by the DAO layer to its above, basically the methods people should be able to access from outside. Things like choosing the provider is handled internally in the DAO layer and therefore not exposed. Basically I do already the thing of hiding concrete classes this way and moreover I have the possibility to theoretically just exchange the DAO dll and everything would still work.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly this doesn't sound right *at all*.

You description of the components isn't really all that...descriptive (can you tell us what you're system does?), but it sounds to me like what you really have is 4 component classes (List, ToDo, Calendar, Money) in one project, one (*always* one) DAL project, and possibly a business logic project. Probably you'll require others. I can't think of any meaning of "DLL" which makes sense in this context.

Nine projects for four logical objects is way too much. Separate code projects by what is logically associated: less is more.